# is there a way to check if a class instance attribute is itself a class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to serialize a python complex class instance to xml however I can't figure out how to determine if any of it's attributes are class instances this is my code.

```
def serialize_model_to_XML(self, modelObject, tagName):
    xml = etree.Element(tagName)
    for attribName, value in modelObject.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(value, type) == '__builtin__': #this line needs to determine if the value of the class attribute is a class instance
            tagElement = self.serialize_model_to_XML(value, attribName)
            xml.append(etree.Element(tagElement))
        else:
            #if not then the key value pair is added as an attribute to the current tag
            xml.attrib[attribName] = value

    return xml
```

Comment: *All* values are instances of *some* class. Do you have a specific class (or classes) in mind that you want `value` to be an instance of?

Comment: I'm trying to keep it as general as possible as there will probably upwards of 30 classes however it could be more given the project is ongoing.

Comment: That's still a limited set of classes compared to *every possible class*. `isinstance` can take a tuple of types as its second argument. E.g., `isinstance(value, (int, float, decimal.Decimal, Foo, Bar, Baz))`.